# How to solve a binomial inequality

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

How to solve the following binomial inequality, the variable in this inequality is k,
$$\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{100}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   100  \\
   i  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}{{0.8}^{i}}{{0.2}^{100-i}}\le \alpha,\alpha>0 $$
I think that the following formula is used, but I can not get its result
$$(x+y)^{n}=\sum _{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{n-k}y^{k}=\sum _{k=0}^{n}{n \choose k}x^{k}y^{n-k}.$$
Please help to suggest me how to find the range of k to satisfy the inequality.

Comment: Since $\alpha$ can be anything, the inequality is true. Define what $\alpha$ is, then we can speak about.

Comment: @Von Neumann, I updated the question, can you please check it?

Comment: @greenworld  Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deeply thinking about this problem, I cannot find any analysis solution for this, because we cannot specify an explicit result of:
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^k{\left( \begin{matrix}
   100  \\
   i  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}{{0.8}^{i}}{{0.2}^{100-i}}$$
I solved this problem by writing a Matlab function to determine k value. It means that I solved it by a numerical method.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{100}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   100  \\
   i  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}{{0.8}^{i}}{{0.2}^{100-i}}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{100}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   100  \\
   i  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}{{0.8}^{i}}{{0.2}^{100-i}}-\sum\limits_{i=0}^k{\left( \begin{matrix}
   100  \\
   i  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}{{0.8}^{i}}{{0.2}^{100-i}}=$$

And now use the binomial expansion you wrote

Comment: Yes, I have thought like yours. But the term:
$$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   100  \\
   i  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}{{0.8}^{i}}{{0.2}^{100-i}}$$
I dont know what is its result, because it has no standard form.

Comment: So $k$ has to be found by brute force?

Comment: k is a variable that we need to determine in this inequality, I don't know how to transform the above term to a standard form.

Comment: @greenworld But that is trivial, since $\;0.8+0.2=1\;$ ...

Comment: Yes, then $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{100}{{}}=1$$

Comment: @greenworld Well, no....

Comment: @DonAntonio, Obviously, (0.8 + 0.2)^100 = 1.

Comment: @greenworld Very obviously, yet that **is not** what $\;\sum\limits_{i=0}^{100}\;$ means...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75344/discussion-between-greenworld-and-donantonio).

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Use that

$$\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{100}...=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{100}...-\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}...$$

Comment: my problem ís how to compute the term $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k}$$, could you please suggest in detail?

Comment: @greenworld You simply need to minimize this sum, that is (since it is the sum of positive terms) assume $k=0$, that is $$\sum\limits_{i=0}^{0}{\left( \begin{matrix}
   100  \\
   i  \\
\end{matrix} \right)}{{0.8}^{i}}{{0.2}^{100-i}}=0.2^{100}$$